# How can I make the options appear in a select dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load the following options in my html, generated in javascript.

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" onClick="input(data)">Add</button>


<select id="processSelect" name="process">
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function input(input){
   //my code
    createOptionsSelectProcess(arrayResponse);
}
function createOptionsSelectProcess(arrayResponse){
    var html = '';
    var arrayLength = arrayResponse.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    html += '<option value="'+ arrayResponse[i] +'">' + arrayResponse[i] 
    + '</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("processSelect").innerHTML = html;
}
```

However, the result I have observed in debug is that the options are generated in the select, but they disappear when the execution is finished. Does anyone know what the reason may be?

Comment: Are you calling `createOptionsSelectProcess` in the `onload`?

Comment: i tried your code and the options dont disappear

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Works - http://jsfiddle.net/4Lhpqg52/

Comment: I'm calling the function inside other function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button type submit will submit the form and refresh the page, use

```
<button type="button" onClick="input(data)">Add</button>
```

Also by default button is of type submit so if you don't put it it will still submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the function `input(input)`. You can use the event listener `submit` to submit the form.

```js
document.addEventListener('submit', () => createOptionsSelectProcess(data))

function createOptionsSelectProcess(arrayResponse) {
    var html = '';
    var arrayLength = arrayResponse.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     html += '<option value="'+ arrayResponse[i] +'">' + arrayResponse[i] + '</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("processSelect").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button>Add</button>
  <select id="processSelect" name="process"></select>
</form>
```

You could use `<button>Add</button>` or `<input type="submit" value="Add">`. They will both submit the form without an `onClick` attribute.